Chosmky - Universal Grammar
I'm a graduate student and I'm struggling with Chomsky's ideas.
I understand the concept of universal grammar as an initial state, in which we are born pre-wired to acquire language.
What I don't understand is how the idea of the principles of languages, aspects that are universal, would manifest in this scenario.
Would it be possibile to say that nowadays there are two different research agendas?
One that tries to explain what is language domain specific - UG?
One that tries to explain language acquisition - P&P?
It's impossible to say anything but this.
